# access cognito from other account from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I am trying to access a Cognito user pool from a different AWS account using the CLI.  I can do this just fine from API Gateway where the user pool is setup as an authorizer, but from the CLI it just says this user pool does not exist.  Is there a way to tell the CLI to look for the user pool in a different account than the one I am in?  I can do this if I switch roles, however I would prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switching roles, you can specify a profile (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html).

For example, in `~/.aws/config` you might have:

```
[profile another]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::account:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
source_profile = default
```

(n.b. your role_arn should be whatever your cross-account role arn actually is)

Then you can use the `--profile` argument in the cli to adopt another role without affecting further commands &c.

For example:

`aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --client-id=$CLIENT_ID --auth-flow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH' --profile=another --region=eu-west-2 --auth-parameters USERNAME='me@example.com',PASSWORD='password'`